# Does anyone knows how to identify between have pp / have been pp?

Tags: american-english

Does anyone knows how to identify between  have pp / have been pp?
I have confused until now.
For example, "i have known" , "i have been known"

Which one is wrong? And why?

Comment: Neither is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, *I have known* would mean that it was I doing the knowing, whereas *I have been known* would mean that someone else is doing the knowing about me. So, the difference is actually active and passive voice.

Answer (score -1):

Have means to possess, own, or hold something that can be a quality, characteristic, or feature.

We use the Present Perfect Continuous `have been` to show that something started in the past and has continued up until now.

Comment: "Have known" is present perfect, "have been known" is present perfect passive. "Have" is only an auxiliary verb here, it does not mean "to possess"